# After closing the file, I do not have access to it

Tags: c++, file-io, fopen, fwrite, fclose

I use this code in a multithreaded program:

```
class A{
public:
    FILE *File;
    bool ThFunc(){
        if (CreateDataFile())
            std::cout << "File was created\n";
        else{
            std::cout << "Can't create file\n";
            return false;
        }

        //work with file

        if (CloseDataFile()){
            std::cout << "File was closed\n";
            return true;
        }
        else{ 
            std::cout << "Can't close file\n";
            return false;
        };
    };

    bool CreateDataFile(){
        File = fopen ("binary_file.bin", "wb");
        if (File!=NULL)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };

    bool CloseDataFile(){
        int t=fclose(File);
        if (t!=0)
            return false;
        else{
            //insert the file name in another thread
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

Sometimes, in another thread (~every 10 files) there is an error: "The file is used by another program(my.exe)", but in console i see: "File was closed". What could be wrong? Mutex is locked, before use a ThFunc() and unlocked after.

Comment: Looks like a treading issue. Such issues are not uncommon. Can you please **fix the indentation**. Oh, and **post the real code**.

Comment: -1 not the real code.

Comment: You should flush `std::cout`. There may be other activity logged that hasn't been sent to the console yet.

Comment: This cut from the real code. Original ~700 lines. Another thread can't write this message.

Comment: @n1k: The code you posted is not valid, so it is definitely not a pure cut from real, compilable code.

Comment: don't just blindly cut. always compile before posting code.

Comment: Some things that may be helpful: use `cerr` for logging (it does not need flushing by default), use `endl` ratner than `\n` in logging (it affects buffering), print file names in logging, including error logging.

Comment: I edited his code for him.. Here is his code: http://ideone.com/CE8Tkl  I don't know how to edit posts yet. @OP, it's `class` not `Class`. There is no capital letter. You were missing semi-colons and you declared functions inside functions.. You don't need to `if-else-statement` basic expressions and return true/false. Just return the expression itself. You do not need semi-colon after if-statements or functions.

Comment: If you edit code that isn't the actual code that actually causes the problem we may well be a step further away from being able to see the problem.

Comment: @doctorlove If you noticed, I haven't removed anything or added anything :l I did not make changes to the code that makes it run any different from what OP has. All I did was format it A-style really.

Comment: @phresnel: sorry, the code is updated.

Comment: @n1k: Please see http://sscce.org/

Comment: @phresnel: If you need to compile the code, I can provide.

Comment: Why not just use C++ file streams like std::fstream?

Comment: @Manu343726, when I use fstream.write () in the file written trash, and fwrite () faster. I write values ​​with 14 sensors

Comment: My problem: after closing, I can not access the file

Comment: @n1k: As said, please see (and READ) http://sscce.org, including the reasoning behind it.